# how to apply css all element whose starting element is same?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

can you please tell me how to apply css all element whose starting element is same.Example I want to apply css whose starting characters of ID is "abc" ?

Answer (score 5):

You can use pure CSS which is better:

```
[id^="abc"] {
    // Your styles here
}
```

If you're looking for jQuery solution then you can use **[attribute starts with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)** along with **[.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/)**:

```
$('[id^="abc"]').css("Your styles here");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Attribute Starts With Selector [name^="value"]](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

jQuery, [css](http://api.jquery.com/css/) function

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/6grf3/1/)**

```
$('[id^=abc]').css('key', 'value');
```

css

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/6grf3/)**

```
[id^="abc"] {
    background-color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily via css itself:

```
[id^="abc"] {
    // mention your style here
}
```

Insert the above code in your css stylesheet file.